# How do I flip a mesh inside-out and still have the object be the same just so the faces are now facing out-words instead of inside the object?

Tags: mesh

I'm making fuzzy boots for a game and everything was going well until I tried to add the fuzz and I discovered that the whole thing was literally inside out and the fuzz (hair) would go inside the boot instead of outside the boot. I need to know if there is a way to not change anything about the topology of the boot but make it so the hair/fuzz goes on the outside instead of the inside. (please help)

Comment: Usually, the answer is "recalculate normals", and if that doesn't do what you want, enable "inside" on the operator panel.  There are potential situations where that won't work; but those potential situations indicate something other than/additional to normals are wrong, and you should fix that other wrong thing.  The other way around this is to just change whatever the fuzz object is, making it point the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "flipping the face normals". A *Normal* is basically the front direction of a geometry element, like vertices, edges, or faces. To see if your faces are oriented the right way, you can use some *Overlay* options in the viewport, both in *Object Mode* and in *Edit Mode*:

[image] [image] <sub>***Left:*** Enabling "Face Orientation" in Object Mode ***Right:*** Enabling "Face Orientation" and "Face Normals" in Edit Mode</sub>

Then in *Edit Mode*, you can select your faces and *Recalculate Normals* by pressing <kbd>Shift + N</kbd>. There are also other operations available in the *Mesh > Normals* menu (<kbd>Alt + N</kbd>), [as explained in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just went to view port overlays and turned on face orientation which showed which Normals were the wrong way and I selected any wrong-facing Normals and flipped them by going to *Mesh > Normals > Flip*